# MySQL - Order by one column for a limit then by another column for a limit

Tags: mysql

I'm developing an application that displays rows which have columns "Time created" and "Number of Likes".

I'm trying to return the first 5 results of my query with the rows that have the most likes, and then the remaining 95 by most recent date, without duplication.

My current query only accomplishes ordering by date.

```
"SELECT * FROM `$category` ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 100"
```

Is what I'm attempting to do possible in one query? Or will I have to perform two queries and filter out duplicate rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` automatically removes duplicate rows and `LIMIT` outside the parethesis applies to the whole query.

```
(SELECT *, like_count AS likes FROM category ORDER BY like_count DESC LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT *, 0 AS likes FROM category ORDER BY time DESC)
ORDER BY likes DESC, time DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: The first 5 items in the result set are sorted by time and not by the number of likes.